# Selenium Webdriver-- getting error while Taking screenshot

Tags: selenium

```
 public void testTakeScreenshot()
  {
      try{

          File fscreenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
          System.out.println(fscreenshot.getPath());

          File fdest = new File("E:/");
          FileUtils.copyFile(fscreenshot,fdest);
          System.out.println(fdest.getPath());

      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Generated Output at console :

C:\Users\Bunty\AppData\Local\Temp\screenshot1773089913844817102.png
java.io.IOException: Destination 'E:\' exists but is a directory

The test is running Ok but the file is created as shown in the console. while copying the link . I couldnt find any file for the same. Also the copy function is not working ; hence  no file is present in E drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the errormessage suggests, you shouldn't give the path to the directory ('E:\'), but the path to the file. Try:

```
File fdest = new File("E:/screenshot.png");
```

Comment: Yes how to generate the filename automatically...Any idea for the same?